# Where does drupal store content-type display settings?

Tags: nodes

I have several similar sites built by drupal. When I finished configuring one site, I wanna clone first site's setting to others(by importing SQL exported from the first site).But I can't find where drupal store content-type(ex:article)'s display setting in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default it stores in field_config_instance table.. For relevant code check below function in field.crud.inc file

```
function _field_write_instance($instance, $update = FALSE) {
  $field = field_read_field($instance['field_name']);
  $field_type = field_info_field_types($field['type']);

  // Set defaults.
  $instance += array(
    'settings' => array(),
    'display' => array(),
    'widget' => array(),
    'required' => FALSE,
    'label' => $instance['field_name'],
    'description' => '',
    'deleted' => 0,
  );

  // Set default instance settings.
  $instance['settings'] += field_info_instance_settings($field['type']);

  // Set default widget and settings.
  $instance['widget'] += array(
    // TODO: what if no 'default_widget' specified ?
    'type' => $field_type['default_widget'],
    'settings' => array(),
  );
  // If no weight specified, make sure the field sinks at the bottom.
  if (!isset($instance['widget']['weight'])) {
    $max_weight = field_info_max_weight($instance['entity_type'], $instance['bundle'], 'form');
    $instance['widget']['weight'] = isset($max_weight) ? $max_weight + 1 : 0;
  }
  // Check widget module.
  $widget_type = field_info_widget_types($instance['widget']['type']);
  $instance['widget']['module'] = $widget_type['module'];
  $instance['widget']['settings'] += field_info_widget_settings($instance['widget']['type']);

  // Make sure there are at least display settings for the 'default' view mode,
  // and fill in defaults for each view mode specified in the definition.
  $instance['display'] += array(
    'default' => array(),
  );
  foreach ($instance['display'] as $view_mode => $display) {
    $display += array(
      'label' => 'above',
      'type' => isset($field_type['default_formatter']) ? $field_type['default_formatter'] : 'hidden',
      'settings' => array(),
    );
    if ($display['type'] != 'hidden') {
      $formatter_type = field_info_formatter_types($display['type']);
      $display['module'] = $formatter_type['module'];
      $display['settings'] += field_info_formatter_settings($display['type']);
    }
    // If no weight specified, make sure the field sinks at the bottom.
    if (!isset($display['weight'])) {
      $max_weight = field_info_max_weight($instance['entity_type'], $instance['bundle'], $view_mode);
      $display['weight'] = isset($max_weight) ? $max_weight + 1 : 0;
    }
    $instance['display'][$view_mode] = $display;
  }

  // The serialized 'data' column contains everything from $instance that does
  // not have its own column and is not automatically populated when the
  // instance is read.
  $data = $instance;
  unset($data['id'], $data['field_id'], $data['field_name'], $data['entity_type'], $data['bundle'], $data['deleted']);

  $record = array(
    'field_id' => $instance['field_id'],
    'field_name' => $instance['field_name'],
    'entity_type' => $instance['entity_type'],
    'bundle' => $instance['bundle'],
    'data' => $data,
    'deleted' => $instance['deleted'],
  );
  // We need to tell drupal_update_record() the primary keys to trigger an
  // update.
  if ($update) {
    $record['id'] = $instance['id'];
    $primary_key = array('id');
  }
  else {
    $primary_key = array();
  }
  drupal_write_record('field_config_instance', $record, $primary_key);
}
```

It stores in above table data column as blob format... Sample example goes below inside blob..

```
a:6:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Comment";s:8:"settings";a:2:{s:15:"text_processing";i:1;s:18:"user_register_form";b:0;}s:8:"required";b:1;s:7:"display";a:1:{s:7:"default";a:5:{s:5:"label";s:6:"hidden";s:4:"type";s:12:"text_default";s:6:"weight";i:0;s:8:"settings";a:0:{}s:6:"module";s:4:"text";}}s:6:"widget";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:13:"text_textarea";s:8:"settings";a:1:{s:4:"rows";i:5;}s:6:"weight";i:0;s:6:"module";s:4:"text";}s:11:"description";s:0:"";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found the answer myself.

I use display suite, so export table with 'ds_' prefix and import them to others is OK.
If using the default display setting, datas probably stored in field_config and field_config_instance..

Comment: This is highly dependent on exactly what configuration you want to copy and can potentially be highly risky in that you can end up with corrupt or incomplete data that will cause you problems. This approach can be useful but I would not recommend it unless you are very familiar with Drupal and the way it stores the specific data (and any data that may have a relationship with the data you are migrating). This includes any 3rd party modules and the way they store their data.